# TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, tweepy, tweetstream

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd

consumer_key="xxxxxx"
consumer_secret="xxxxxxx"
access_token="xxxx-xxxx"
access_token_secret="xxxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
from tweepy.streaming import Stream
class Listener(tweepy.Stream):

  def on_status(self, status):
    print(status.user.screen_name + ":" + status.text)

stream_tweet = Listener(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

#streams by keyword 

keywords = ['2022', '#python']

stream_tweet.filter(track=keywords)
```

**Error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-4c388804967a> in <module>()
      8 
      9 
---> 10 stream_tweet = Listener(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
     11 
     12 #streams by keyword

TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: Show code and the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Can you help me out

Comment: What is your `init()`? You must have defined this function beforehand with three arguments, but right now you are giving it 5 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This handles Twitter authentication and connection to Twitter Streaming API
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, Listener())
    stream.filter(track=['python'])
```

Used this code : Working

Answer (score 0):

You're using Tweepy v4 syntax with an older version of Tweepy (e.g. Tweepy v3.10.0).
[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) changed `Stream` to allow passing credentials like that when initializing, instead of `auth` and `listener` parameters.